# Wrapping a memory address as std::atomic

Tags: c++11

I have:

```
int* p = 0xf
```

How can I wrap `p` as `std::atomic<int>`?
I would like someting like:

```
std::atomic<int> wp = wrap(p);
wp.store(100);
```

And `wp.store(100)` stored `100` to `0xf`

Comment: Since you don't appear to mind casts that exhibit undefined behavior, why not `std::atomic<int>& wp = *reinterpet_cast<std::atomic<int>*>(0xf);`

Comment: The problem is that you generally can't depend on an atomic<int> being the same size as an undecorated int, or that its alignment requirements are the same. The next best safe thing would be if your wrapper brought in a mutex guard, but that comes at a cost.